Trouble using safe-api-kit
I'm having some trouble using the safe-api-kit, even the quick start example is failing.
Quick start example:
import SafeApiKit from '@safe-global/api-kit'

const apiKit = new SafeApiKit({
  chainId: 1n,
  txServiceUrl: 'https://safe-transaction-mainnet.safe.global'
})

I get the following error:

TypeError: SafeApiKit is not a constructor
at  (/home/jvf/Github_docs/safe_vault_testing/testing.ts:5:16)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12)"


Try doing this:
const apiKit = new SafeApiKit.default({
  chainId: chainID,
});


That did the trick! Thanks : )
